# CKEDITOR Replaces <b> with <strong> And Other Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor

I'm currently using CKEDITOR inline editing and I have a somewhat of big issue with it. CKEDITOR for some reason is replacing some tags automatically. So far I have noticed that my "B" tags are changed to "STRONG" and "I" with "EM".

How can I disable tag replacing in CKEDITOR?

This is how I'm initiating and using CKEDITOR

```
function ckEditorInit() {
    $("#canvas.ckeditor-on").find("[edit='true']").each(function() {
        CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.span = 1;
        CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1;
        CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.li = 1;
        CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.b = 1;
        CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.i = 1;
        $(this).ckeditor();
    });
}
```

Comment: why would this be a big issue in the first place? What are the ramifications?

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_bold

Answer (score 1):

The output of the so-called "basic text styles" (bold, italic, underline, strikethrough) is customizable through configuration options, so you can easily switch to using a different HTML or even a class/style to output bold and italic. You can [read more here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basicstyles-section-custom-basic-text-style-definition) and [see the sample with source code here](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/basicstyles.html) (scroll down to the "Custom Basic Text Styles Definition" section below).

The [configuration values](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) that are interesting for you are:

- [config.coreStyles_bold](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_bold)
- [config.coreStyles_italic](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_italic)
- [config.coreStyles_underline](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_underline)
- [config.coreStyles_strike](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_strike)
- [config.coreStyles_subscript](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_subscript)
- [config.coreStyles_superscript](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_superscript)